# Как удалить все файлы, кроме нужных (по маске) в каталогах

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть каталог с вложенными каталогами в 3 уровня. В каждой папке есть файлы *F (имя файла заканчивается на F и без расширения) и другие файлы (также без расширений). Файлы есть как в корневом каталоге, так и во вложенных. Могут встречаться пустые каталоги.

Как удалить все файлы, кроме *F ? Оставить при этом структуру папок в прежнем виде.

В интернете много информации на этот счет, но нигде не нашел именно такой задачи. Удаётся удалять файлы только в корне. Вложенные папки пропускаю, так как не знаю, что с ними делать.

```py
def clear_catalog(src):
    file_list = os.listdir(src)
    for item in file_list:
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            pass
        else:
            if str(is.path.basename(s)).endwith('F'):
                pass
            else:
                os.remove(s)
```

Comment: Рекурсивно обойти вложенности и удалить не нужные файлы.

Comment: Добавил код. Правда, с телефона это трудно форматировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто для вложенных директорий рекурсивно вызывайте ту же функцию:

```py
def clear_catalog(src):
    file_list = os.listdir(src)
    for item in file_list:
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            clear_catalog(s)
        else:
            if str(os.path.basename(s)).endswith('F'):
                pass
            else:
                os.remove(s)
```

Также, по-хорошему условие для удаление стоит передавать аргументом, как регулярное выражение или функцию:

```py
def clear_catalog(src, checker):
    file_list = os.listdir(src)
    for item in file_list:
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            clear_catalog(s)
        else:
            if checker(str(os.path.basename(s))):
                os.remove(s)

# Пример вызова:
clear_catalog(some_path, lambda path: not path.endswith('F'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Такие вещи удобнее делать используя [`glob` подобные функции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#Path.glob):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"c:\temp\test")

for f in path.glob("**/*"):
     if <condition>:
         # ...
```

---

в вашем случае:

```
for f in path.glob("**/*"):
     if not str(f).endswith("F"):
         f.unlink()
```

---

в виде функции:

```
def clear_catalog(path, chk_func):
    path = Path(path)
    for f in path.glob("**/*"):
        if chk_func(f):
            f.unlink()
```

Пример:

```
In [31]: path = Path(r"c:\temp\test")
```

список директорий и файлов до удаления:

```
In [32]: list(path.glob("**/*"))
Out[32]:
[WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/file_01'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/file_01'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1/a2'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1/file_01'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1/a2/file_01'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/b1'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/file_01'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/b1/file_02F')]

In [33]: clear_catalog(path, chk_func=lambda f: f.is_file() and not f.name.endswith("F"))
```

список директорий и файлов после удаления:

```
In [34]: list(path.glob("**/*"))
Out[34]:
[WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1/a2'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/a/a1/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/b1'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/file_02F'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/b/b1/file_02F')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Для рекурсивного обхода каталогов стоит использовать средства стандартной библиотеки языка:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

def remover(path, pattern='*F'):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if not Path(f).match(pattern):
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
```